# react native dynamic comment avatar image

Tags: android, react-native

I am using react-native and I need to display user comments under an item description. While the text is not a problem, as it renders properly I have problems with user avatars in  component.
The `source` attribute is

```
source={{
    uri: `https://example.com/avatars/${avatar.id}.jpg`
}}
```

The `<Image />` renders well on emulated device but on actual Android 8.1 device (Honor 10) it does not work. Image container is rendered but no image appears and no error is returned in `onError` event. The same happens on Android 5.0 device (MyPhone Infinity II LTE).

The problem is that I do not know at compile time what users will I have registered and what avatars they will have.

I could use `<WebView />` to display the image but it does not seem to be good practice.

How can I display the mentioned avatars?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By experience, I prefer not to use the default Image component in react-native, it has a lot of drawbacks.

I personally use https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image to handle remote images and it works really well.

Let me know if it helps !

Comment: Works like a charm. I was looking for something like this but I could not find anything close to your answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

So as stated [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481#issuecomment-137982505) , React Native doesn't support dynamic images out of the box, but reading that forum further a suggested method could be [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2481#issuecomment-305058573), I had answered a similar question some time back [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939111/react-native-dynamic-images/50939325#50939325)