# asset Images not displaying in flat list expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

**EDIT:**

I found the answer to my problem here:
[React Native Dynamic Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939111/react-native-dynamic-images)

I have a categories screen, and for each category, I want an image displayed.
I'm trying to display images in a flat list along with the category name. 
The images are coming from the assets' folder, if I hard code the value of the image source

```
source={require("../../assets/image.png")}
```

Then the image displays, but then obviously the same image gets displayed for every item in the flat list.

(In my code example below, I have only included the iconSrc for 2 items, as If I can get 2 working, I can get them all working.)

I have 12 images in the assets' folder, one for each category.
I have flat lists in other parts of the app, which are getting the images from firestore and displaying them fine, but just cant seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

```
export default class CategoriesScreen extends Component {
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = {
  CategoryItems: [
    {key: "All Events", iconSrc: "../../assets/categoryicons/calendar.png"},
    {key: "Music", iconSrc: "../../assets/categoryicons/music.png"},
    {key: "Food & Drink"},
    {key: "Theatre"},
    {key: "Charities & Causes"},
    {key: "Talk"},
    {key: "Health & Wellbeing"},
    {key: "Art"},
    {key: "Family"},
    {key: "Comedy"},
    {key: "Sports & Fitness"},
    {key: "Other"}
  ]
};
}

render() {
return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <FlatList
      data={this.state.CategoryItems}
      renderItem={({item}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity
          delayPressIn={50}
          onPress={this.onCategoryItemClick.bind(this, item.key)}
          style={styles.GridViewContainer}>
          {/*<Ionicons name={item.iconName} size={80} color="#0075B4" />*/}
          <Image
            style={{height: 80, width: 80}}
            source={{uri: item.iconSrc}}
          />

          <Text style={styles.GridViewTextLayout}>{item.key}</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      numColumns={2}
    />
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the code I'm looking at is your code, there's only one picture file in the list of CategoryItems. So, you can only show one picture.

And avoiding variables with the same name is good for the code.

example FlatListData:

```js
sitterdata = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image:
      "https://postfiles.pstatic.net/MjAxOTAxMTVfMjk3/MDAxNTQ3NTEzMDI1MDEx.ODD9YUUNc5YSk4Zz1wTgxmpf_BRr154ekJ-vJQ1f3ocg.u1uIXInfJ3O2PTKFmKFaI46epH_e8IzD5TEB96K-eF4g.PNG.dea972/%EC%8A%A4%ED%81%AC%EB%A6%B0%EC%83%B7_2019-01-15_%EC%98%A4%EC%A0%84_9.42.43.png?type=w966",
    introduce: "hi hello",
    address: "Rondon",
    user:
      "https://postfiles.pstatic.net/MjAxOTAxMTVfOTQg/MDAxNTQ3NTEyODU0NDk4.DcAvlx3CGY9pGFlgWZA7mIr6_SCt8h_gGaHYGAFlDIYg.bQ9kBiykOzlbxyIyQ3nTCO7lGw4NVmmIeDV7pz0OX94g.PNG.dea972/%EC%8A%A4%ED%81%AC%EB%A6%B0%EC%83%B7_2019-01-15_%EC%98%A4%EC%A0%84_9.28.54.png?type=w966",
    by: "bon"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    image:
      "https://postfiles.pstatic.net/MjAxOTAxMTVfMTMx/MDAxNTQ3NTEzMDMzMDgx.SbY_nsX7oK4UlZGzre6U5dLHinRfCoAYyvnSzXuZR7cg.5K3sX7E0bDpgyzDifD174hfQBOnJDtLVFqTe8BHH7Gcg.PNG.dea972/%EC%8A%A4%ED%81%AC%EB%A6%B0%EC%83%B7_2019-01-15_%EC%98%A4%EC%A0%84_9.42.57.png?type=w966",
    introduce: "nihao",
    address: "china",
    user:
      "https://postfiles.pstatic.net/MjAxOTAxMTVfMjU2/MDAxNTQ3NTEyODY3MTE2.X4LDN12uIgRkOFrUChl0s9UnKiu9VOPEOkWbIRHPDpgg.DrmXUbVURwsTuGs5dlOL_wugRf1nnANxWSIN4jYkdX0g.PNG.dea972/%EC%8A%A4%ED%81%AC%EB%A6%B0%EC%83%B7_2019-01-15_%EC%98%A4%EC%A0%84_9.29.23.png?type=w966",
    by: "son"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    image:
      "https://postfiles.pstatic.net/MjAxOTAxMTVfOTIg/MDAxNTQ3NTEzMDM3MDAy.p_CNMU7vlCaELYpfuqf6H9GrCEPe9BzFdeNojFuKGc4g.65lwFvImqL2QgC01mNPzIUbY0tgBz4lukZplv9NZkJAg.PNG.dea972/%EC%8A%A4%ED%81%AC%EB%A6%B0%EC%83%B7_2019-01-15_%EC%98%A4%EC%A0%84_9.43.14.png?type=w966",
    introduce: "haha",
    address: "New York",
    user:
      "https://postfiles.pstatic.net/MjAxOTAxMTVfMjY4/MDAxNTQ3NTEzMDE5MDI2.fmBkO0W8lFwWCzo3KrJ3EDkTTZ_NmAKH0wlF050XMcYg.GJ8JTbs5nQNosj1ZhkK-1lm-ah2LIAN7i_d3hjIQ4K8g.PNG.dea972/%EC%8A%A4%ED%81%AC%EB%A6%B0%EC%83%B7_2019-01-15_%EC%98%A4%EC%A0%84_9.42.09.png?type=w966",
    by: "jhon"
  }
]
```

renderItem example:

```js
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight style={styles.containerCell}>
        <View>
          <TouchableOpacity
            onPress={() => this.showAlert(this.props.navigation)}
          >
            <Image
              style={{
                width: width,
                height: 180,
                resizeMode: "stretch"
              }}
              source={{ uri: item.image }}
            />
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <View style={styles.footerContainer}>
            <View style={styles.petImageUrl}>
              <Image
                style={styles.imageAvatar}
                source={{ uri: item. user }}
              />
            </View>
            <View style={styles.footerTextContainer}>
              <Text style={styles.text}>{item.introduce}</Text>
              <Text style={[styles.text2, styles.textTitle]}>
                {item.address}
              </Text>
              <Text style={[styles.text2, styles.textBy]}>By {item.by}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </View>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  };
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer, I have added in more images to my data, I only had1 in because I knew If I could get one working, I could get all 12 working.

Comment: also can you show me an example of how you do this with a flat list

Comment: I put up an example of applying 'rederItem If my answer is correct, please choose an answer.

Comment: Hi @hong develop, thank you for your answer and effort, but I ended up using this SO answer in the end : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939111/react-native-dynamic-images