# Importing dynamic filenames into React-Native

Tags: react-native

I have a menu.json file with hundreds of items in it:

```
menu_items = [
    {
       name: "Category 1",
       file: "cat1.json"
    },
    {
       name: "Category 2",
       file: "cat2.json"
    },
    {
       name: "Category 3",
       file: "cat3.json"
    },
    {
       name: "Category 4",
       file: "cat4.json"
    },
    {
       name: "Category 5",
       file: "cat15.json"
    }
]
```

I am able to read the menu.json file. I then create a Scrollable List showing each of the entries. When a user clicks on the entry, I want to load another screen that imports the specified json file.

Currently, when someone clicks an item in the list, the following module is loaded:

```
<DisplayItem file_name={this.state.selected_file} />
```

Then in my DisplayItem I have the following:

```
const item_data = require('./' + this.props.file_name);
```

However, I get the error:

```
Invalid call at line 52: require(file)
```

Apparently, I am unable to do imports or requires when the filename is dynamic. The only solutions I have seen is to manually require all of them first of all.

I find this solution a bit challenging because then I end up with redundant data. Any time I update the menu.json file then I have to remember to make the exact same update to the module requiring all the json files.

Is there a more efficient way to do this that eliminates the redundancy issue?

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939111/react-native-dynamic-images/50939325

Answer (score 0):

As I know You can't require a file in react native from a dynamic value, because it will make the compiler doesn't know which file to be included when building the app.

As written in [React-Native's Image documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images)

> In order for this to work, the image name in require has to be known
>   statically.

For example

```
// GOOD
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />;


// BAD
var icon = this.props.active ? 'my-icon-active' : 'my-icon-inactive';
<Image source={require('./' + icon + '.png')} />;


// GOOD
var icon = this.props.active ? require('./my-icon-active.png') : require('./my-icon-inactive.png');

<Image source={icon} />;
```