# Trying to add image file paths React Native Image source

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-paper

I am attempting to set up an Image component source in React Native to dynamically receive image file paths from a separate JSON file.

In my JSON file, I have the following image paths set up to point to their respective distance from the component:

```
[
  {
    "name": "AppleBees",
    "imgAlias": "../assets/logos/applebees-logo.jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Arbys",
    "imgAlias": "../assets/logos/arbys-logo.jpg"
  },
  {
    "name": "Buffalo Wild Wings",
    "imgAlias": "../assets/logos/buffalo-wild-wings-logo.jpg"
  },
]
```

After importing the JSON file into the App component, I pointed the source of `<Image /> to` uri: images.imgAlias```,

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Image } from 'react-native';
import images from './imageMapping.json'; // Adjust the path as needed

const App = () => {
  return (
    <View>
        <View>
          <Image source={{ uri: images.imgAlias }} style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }} />
        </View>
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

However, when running the app in the Expo iOS simulator, I get the following error for each image file path:

```
WARN  Could not find image file:///Users/<user>/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C7953177-036A-4314-B568-5EA33D83D036/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/A175C521-F657-46A4-9A67-D1F8337C3D1F/Exponent-2.29.4.tar.app/../assets/logos/applebees-logo.jpg
```

To resolve this, I tried changing the source to the following:

```
source={require(images.imgAlias)}
```

but then I get the following error:

```
Invalid call at line 85: require(item.img)]
Error: components/App.js:Invalid call at line 85: require(item.img)
```

Finally, I tried simply adding:

```
source={images.imgAlias}
```

...but that also returns the first error I mentioned.

How can I go about properly setting up the Image source to dynamically receive image file paths from the JSON file?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native Dynamic Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50939111/react-native-dynamic-images)

Comment: Absolutely! It didn't occur to me before that I could just refactor the image library as a JS file instead of JSON then add a require wrapper around each object file path. I did that and it worked. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Write the json data in this format

```
[
 {
   "name": "AppleBees",
   "imgAlias":require("../assets/logos/applebees-logo.jpg")
 },
]
```

and use it in the below format after importing

```
<Image source={images.imgAlias} />
```